# Rubyのエラー/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/uri/rfc3986_parser.rb:67:in `split': bad URI(is not URI?): h (URI::InvalidURIError)ntent/base

Tags: ruby

http://tbpgr.hatenablog.com/entry/20130817/1376761958
上記サイトのスクリプトを利用しようとすると

下記エラーがでます。

```
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/uri/rfc3986_parser.rb:67:in `split': bad URI(is not URI?): h (URI::InvalidURIError)ntent/base
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/uri/rfc3986_parser.rb:73:in `parse'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/uri/common.rb:227:in `parse'
    from epw.rb:67:in `get_pronunciation'
    from epw.rb:55:in `append_word'
    from epw.rb:42:in `block in get_words_htmls'
    from epw.rb:42:in `each'
    from epw.rb:42:in `get_words_htmls'
    from epw.rb:18:in `output_html'
    from epw.rb:101:in `<main>'
```

環境はVM上Ubuntu16.04でRuby2.3　Nokogiri導入済みです。
Rubyは触ったことがなく困惑しています。どうかよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: Weblio のウェブサイトの HTML を見ますと、構成が変更されている様です。例えば、`WMV_XPATH` は`//div[@id='ePsdDl']/a/@href` にしないとマッチしませんし、音声ファイルは WAV フォーマットではなく、MP3 になっています。これらの変更に合わせて epw.rb を修正する必要があります。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。上記2点修正しましたが、結果かわらず。このエラーは本当にウェブサイトの構成変更によるものなのでしょうか？てっきりバージョン互換の問題か何かかと思い、エラーなく走るようになってから、サイトの構成変更に対応していくつもりでした。

Comment: [こちら](https://paiza.io/projects/e/gZ8clUQAH7GEvIkMkJVHTg)が修正したものです。paiza.io の playground 上では外部ファイルが使えないので実行できませんが、ローカル環境(ruby 2.5.1)では想定通りに動作しています(epw.words はそのままです)。

Comment: 私の用意したepw.wordsがWindows側で用意したものであり、その改行コードがURI.parseで悪さをしているようでした。お騒がせして申し訳ありませんでした。修正したファイルまで提示していただき、本当にありがとうございました。